# Does ADAL.js support the new Authorization code grant with PKCE extensions?

Tags: oauth-2.0, adal.js

Per the new security guidelines at https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/, the implicit flow is not recommended. Since ADAL.js uses the implicit flow, will it be affected and is it recommended to use ADAl.js implicit flow for new applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I agree that as per the new guidelines, the implicit flow is not recommending. Currently, ADAL js uses the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow and it does not return refresh token for security reasons(refresh tokens have longer lifetime than access tokens and are therefore more dangerous in the hands of malicious actors).

It is designed to return an ID token when the resource for which the token is being requested is the same as the client application. When an ID token is returned, it cached by the library.
So when we use **authenticationContext.acquireToken(resource, callback)**, it allows the application to obtain tokens silently without prompting the user again. ADAL js uses a hidden Iframe to make the token request to Azure AD.

But to use PKCE flow, we can make a http post call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/outh2/authorize endpoint by passing **code_challenge** along with other parameters in the body and gets the authorization code. And use that code and make a call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/outh2/token endpoint by passing **code_verifier** along with other parameters in the body and gets the token.

If you are using SPA, and have no backend components or intend to invoke a web API via JavaScript, use the OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow.
But if you have a backend component and you are consuming an API from the backend code then implicit flow is not a good fit. In that case you can use OAuth2.0 auth code grant flow or OAuth2.0 client credential grant flow, it provides the ability to obtain tokens that reflect the permissions assigned to the application itself.